# Issue on Linking to Custom Post Type Meta

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, metadata, wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type and a text input metadat for URL. Things works fine for me so far unless when I want to echo the meta to a href"" in button.
Here is what I have

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<button type="button" class="> <a href="'.<?php echo $meta['source'][0];?>.'" target="_blank"> Read More @ News Source</a></button>';
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<?php echo`  and `?>`. Its not required as your concatenating the string

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<button type="button"> <a href="'.$meta['source'][0].'" target="_blank"> Read More @ News Source</a></button>';
```

Also not sure what `class="` is before..

### Update

Surrounding the link with a `<button>` tag will make the link un-clickable as a button tag should not be used in this context.

Change it to a `span` instead

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<span type="button"> <a href="'.$meta['source'][0].'" target="_blank"> Read More @ News Source</a></span>';
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, it is working in chrome but not in Firefox! can you please let me know why? Here is the link of page: http://teddybearfamilychildcare.com/kids-news/

Comment: @MonaCoder Ctrl-U Will show you that the Menu on the side has invalide markup E.G `<li>Supports</li style="list-style-type:square;">`

Comment: Well, I think I fix the errors on the markup but still not working on Firefox!